# Complete Lattice with unique negation

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Suppose i have a complete lattice (meet and join exist for any two subsets of the lattice) and for every element of the lattice, there is a unique element that is its complement (hence a Boolean negation). If such a lattice is also modular, then it is Boolean. Negation is a strong requirement.. 
If i don't know it is modular, then what kind of lattice is this?
What if the lattice is also atomic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are lattices with unique complements that are not Boolean: In his article ["Lattices with unique complements"](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1945-057-01/S0002-9947-1945-0012263-6/S0002-9947-1945-0012263-6.pdf), R.P. Dilworth proves that every lattice can be embedded into a lattice with unique complements. So take any non-modular lattice (e.g. $N_5$). This may be embdedded into a lattice $L$ with unique complements. Then $L$ cannot be modular since it contains a non-modular sublattice.

In this [book review of "Lattices with Unique Complements" by V. N. Salii](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-22/issue-2/Review-V-N-Sali%C4%AD-Lattices-with-Unique-Complements/bams/1183555629.full) the author mentions at the end that the question whether there exist *complete* non-distributive lattices with unique complements is still unsolved (by 1990).

However it is true that every *atomic* complete lattice with unique complements is Boolean (and isomorphic to the power set lattice of its atoms). For a proof, see Theorem 18 in §6 of G. Birkhoff's book "Lattice theory".

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative reply. That i could not find anything about it, had to mean it was either a silly or a very difficult question. ( Now i know!) I downloaded your references and will look at them . Thanks once more!